# WCF service consume, no response at all

Tags: wcf, proxy

Sorry to bother you guys again.

I am going to consume a WCF service on a server. The service was created by outside. If I look at it in the browser, it is fine. Please see the image below.

[image: service.]

To consume it, I add service reference. with the url `http://wsvc01/BOERPI/BOERPI.svc`
Then I instantiate the proxy by the code.

```
BOERPI.PostPhoneCallResponse client = null;
client = new BOERPI.PostPhoneCallResponse();
double x = client.ActualCallCharge; // suppose to get a proper value but not
```

Some of the code of the service is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface iBOERPI
{
    [OperationContract]
    PostPhoneCallResponse PostPhoneCall(PostPhoneCallRequest objCDRRequest);
[DataContract]
public class PostPhoneCallResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public double ActualCallCharge = -1.0;
```

I assume the service code is 100% right, is any thing wrong when I consume the service?

When I righted click the definition of PostPhoneCallResponse, it is:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="PostPhoneCallResponse", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/nsBOERPI")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class PostPhoneCallResponse : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private double ActualCallChargeField;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client = new BOERPI.PostPhoneCallResponse();` You are trying to use your `DataContract` here instead of Service client.

Check under Service References for your service name you used in your client application and 
use it:

eg.

[image]

```
using(var client = new BingMapsGeocodeService()) // This should be your service client name
{

}
```

**Update:**

Sending and Received messages using request and response objects:

You need to create a request object as per your operation shows:

```
var request = new PostPhoneCallRequest(){ // populate all your properties you need to send to the service};

var client = new BOERPI.MyClient(); // Instantiate your client with the name you have given for your service client.

PostPhoneCallResponse response = client.PostPhoneCall(request); // You are sending your request and getting a response as PostPhoneCallResponse object
```

Comment: I have two DataContract, I just gave one in the example.

Comment: Yes. But its not your service client. It is the one you name when adding a service reference. Check under service references for your project.

Comment: I meant I want return two objects from two DataContract "PostPhoneCallResponse" and "Messages", but the url address only can type one, how to?

Comment: You can return almost anything from the service operation... You should be returning a Response object, and adding whatever you want to return from the operation as properties of that Response object.

Comment: Your `PostPhoneCallResponse` object has properties like `ActualCallCharge` etc you can access from your call's response.

Comment: I don't need send request, it is created inside the service. So I want to clarify it, when you add the service, the url is http://wsvc01/BOERPI/BOERPI.svc/PostPhoneCallResponse? Can you confirm it and add update2? Please keep the current update?

Comment: By definition, a service is called (requested) by a client... not sure I understand what your question here is...